# Sql: Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm trying to DataBind to a GridView control, but it consistently fails.

Given the following code (sql expanded over multiple lines for readability):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string dsn = "foo";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT F.Project AS 'Project Number', F.Account AS   
             'Account', F.Pd AS Period, F.Incurred AS Totals, C.Project AS 
             'Project Name' FROM Ultron.Final F INNER JOIN Ultron.Custom  
              C ON F.Project = C.Project WHERE F.Project LIKE '61000.003%' AND 
              F.Account NOT LIKE '%-01' AND F.Fy = YEAR(GetDate()) ) Budget PIVOT 
              (SUM(Totals) FOR Period in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
              [11],[12]) AS PivotTable";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dsn))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    testGrid.DataSource = reader;
    testGrid.DataBind();
}
}
```

I'm sure the error has something to do with the parentheses in the query, but those are required for the query to work. When testing in SSMS the query passes without issue.

How do I restructure this so the code doesn't fail?

**EDIT**

I was missing `As PivotTable` to the end of the SQL query. It works now. Sorry, this was an innocent typo. Thanks for all who responded.

Comment: You are missing a space between `BudgetPIVOT`.  If you remove the SQL from your code, you should try to execute it in SSMS, that will help you debug your issue.

Comment: Can you turn your hard-coded query into a stored procedure and just call that SP?

Comment: `BudgetPIVOT` should be `Budget PIVOT` ? Or this is just a copy past mistake?

Comment: This is why it's important to format your SQL.

Comment: You should always run your query first in a sql editor to make sure it works.  As other OPs mentioned, you have several syntax errors.  You also did not show what the error was that you got initially.  That would have been helpful.

Comment: Please stop downvoting. It was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing space and closing `)`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   string dsn = "foo";
   string sql = @"SELECT * FROM 
                  (
                     SELECT F.Project AS 'Project Number', F.Account AS   
                          'Account', F.Pd AS Period, F.Incurred AS Totals, C.Project AS 
                          'Project Name' FROM Ultron.Final F INNER JOIN Ultron.Custom  
                          C ON F.Project = C.Project 
                     WHERE 
                          F.Project LIKE '61000.003%' AND 
                          F.Account NOT LIKE '%-01' AND F.Fy = YEAR(GetDate()) 
                   ) Budget PIVOT 
                   (
                     SUM(Totals) FOR Period in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                     [11],[12])
                   )";
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dsn))
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
   {
       conn.Open();
       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       testGrid.DataSource = reader;
       testGrid.DataBind();
   }
}
```

But really you should create a stored procedure for something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetProjectBudgetInfo]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM 
                      (
                         SELECT F.Project AS 'Project Number', F.Account AS   
                              'Account', F.Pd AS Period, F.Incurred AS Totals, C.Project AS 
                              'Project Name' FROM Ultron.Final F INNER JOIN Ultron.Custom  
                              C ON F.Project = C.Project 
                         WHERE 
                              F.Project LIKE '61000.003%' AND 
                              F.Account NOT LIKE '%-01' AND F.Fy = YEAR(GetDate()) 
                       ) Budget PIVOT 
                       (
                         SUM(Totals) FOR Period in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
                       )

END
```

And then call it in code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   string dsn = "foo";
   string sql = @"GetProjectBudgetInfo";
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dsn))
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
   {
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       conn.Open();
       SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
       testGrid.DataSource = reader;
       testGrid.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I counted correctly, you are missing a parenthesis at the end of your statement.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT F.Project AS 'Project Number', F.Account AS   
             'Account', F.Pd AS Period, F.Incurred AS Totals, C.Project AS 
             'Project Name' FROM Ultron.Final F INNER JOIN Ultron.Custom  
              C ON F.Project = C.Project WHERE F.Project LIKE '61000.003%' AND 
              F.Account NOT LIKE '%-01' AND F.Fy = YEAR(GetDate()) ) Budget PIVOT 
              (SUM(Totals) FOR Period in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
              [11],[12]))";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is missing a last `)` on your sql query. Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string dsn = "foo";
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT F.Project AS 'Project Number', F.Account AS   
                 'Account', F.Pd AS Period, F.Incurred AS Totals, C.Project AS 
                 'Project Name' FROM Ultron.Final F INNER JOIN Ultron.Custom  
                  C ON F.Project = C.Project WHERE F.Project LIKE '61000.003%' AND 
                  F.Account NOT LIKE '%-01' AND F.Fy = YEAR(GetDate()) ) BudgetPIVOT  
                  (SUM(Totals) FOR Period in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                  [11],[12]))";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dsn))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        testGrid.DataSource = reader;
        testGrid.DataBind();
    }
}
```